# Indexes of removed leading/trailing zeros from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 1D array

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 83, 120, 111, 31, 37, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I can remove the leading/trailing zeros using [`numpy.trim_zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html)

```
np.trim_zeros(arr)
array([  8,  83, 120, 111,  31,  37,  10])
```

But I also need the *indexes* of the removed elements, or at least the indexes of the most extreme ones. In the above case, these would be

```
[5, 13]
```

I could do this with a `for` loop checking each element to see if the one processed before was `0` and stopping when this condition is False, but I'm wondering if there's a `numpy` function already developed that could accomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `argmax()` -

```
In [40]: m = arr!=0

In [41]: m.argmax()-1, m.size - m[::-1].argmax()
Out[41]: (5, 13)
```

With `arr` as all `zeros` or all `non-zeros`, we need to define the expected output if those are to be dealt too.

Comment: That's a clever use of arrays. Thanks Divakar!